# How to collapse/expand table on click in a php loop

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to let specific tables collapse and expand under each statement. This is in the context of a php loop. The php loop fetches data from php my admin and like this populates the statements and the tables under each statement. So what I want is for the tables not to show, and on click of the statements, show the table corresponding to it.

I've tried creating a script as such:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var a = false;

    var collapse = "p"+ "<?php echo $collapse ?>";
    var collapse2 = "btn"+"<?php $collapse ?>";




    document.getElementById(collapse2).onclick = function (){
        if(a== false){
            document.getElementById(collapse).style.height = "auto";
            a =true;
        }else{
            document.getElementById(collapse).style.height = "0px";
            a =false;
        }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Because I thought every ID should be specific.. [Edit] Now I put the id's to change specifically everytime the loop is repeated. But it still doesn't work.

This is the php loop

```
<?php

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM stellingen WHERE REGIOID=1;")) {
    $amountOfStellingen = 0;
    while ($amountOfStellingen < 4) {
        mysqli_data_seek($result, $amountOfStellingen);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $collapse = $amountOfStellingen;
        $stellingid = $row["Stelling_ID"];
        echo '<div class="stelling-wrapper" id="btn' . $collapse . '">
        <img src="images/button.svg" alt="Show more..." class="btn" id="bton">
        <p class="stelling">';
        echo "<p>{$row["Stelling"]}</p>";
        echo '<div id="p' . $collapse . '">
        <table id="tabel" border=1px class="data">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Source</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
        </div>
        </div>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="script/collapse.js">';
        echo '</script>';
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM stelling WHERE stelling_iD=$stellingid;";
        $records1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
        $recordscheck = mysqli_num_rows($records1);

        if ($recordscheck > 0) {
            while ($stelling = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records1)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $stelling['Title'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $stelling['Source'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $stelling['Wheight'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $stelling['Timer'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
        $amountOfStellingen += 1;
        echo '</table>';


    }
}

?>
```

I expect each table to collapse/expand at the moment that the specified btn/statement is clicked.

Comment: Yes, IDs must be unique within an HTML document. (So in cases like this, it is often preferable not to use IDs to select/find elements to begin with, but their relation in the DOM structure.) But your HTML is faulty in multiple other aspects as well, that’s stuff you are going to have to fix first. There is no such thing as `<p type="button"`, paragraph elements can not be nested, and you can not insert `div` elements are arbitrary positions in a table either.

Comment: @04FS thank you for helping. I put the table inside the div because the table itself did not react my collapse exapand script  when I first sketched it in html. But when I put the table in a div and toggled the div, then it would. I took the P type button away.. I thought maybe it would create a clicking cursor when hovering... and I'll look into what a DOM structure is.

Comment: @04FS If I understood correctly with the DOM structure, its how I structure the code. Now, maybe what you mean is that I should place the script correctly, so I'll try this.

Comment: No, what I meant was, instead of using IDs to find elements in the DOM - which easily leads into trouble with such a repeating structure, you need to make the IDs unique, your JS code probably needs to get written multiples times - you use the relation of elements in the DOM to find where you need to “go”. When one of your statements gets clicked, don’t try to find the corresponding table to show via an ID, but based on its relation to the statement - like access the following sibling in the DOM, look for a following sibling with a specific class name, or something like that.

Comment: And I wasn’t talking about the table inside a div, that is fine - but stuff like this `</tr></div></div>` is not. At _that level_ of a table you can not introduce div elements - the table row needs to be a child of thead/tbody/tfoot or the table itself. You can not mix in divs there for any kind of “grouping” purposes.